# Yo Generator: EPERM operation not permitted on .config

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Attempting to start up a yo generated project and running into the following error (running on osx):

```
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted '/Users/<user>/.config'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:642:18)
    at sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:70:13)
    at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:76:24)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:41:13)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:26:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:123:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I understand this is a permissions error, and it wouldn't be such a problem if I could just find the .config directory that the permission error is occurring on. I've got hidden files turned on and I am not seeing .config anywhere. I did try changing the permissions on the node_modules/configstore, as I've seen reference to that directory in regards to EPERM errors when using yo, but to no effect.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the instance anyone else comes across this problem, the issue for me ended up being that the folder was "locked". To remedy this, right click / ctrl+click your user folder and select Get Info. Under the General subheading, deselect "Locked".

Hope this helps anyone else who stumbles across this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with jhipster-generator in Windows 10, the cause is before that, a command jhipster to gererate source code is crashed and not completed properly.

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\insight-nodejs\Config\insight-generator-jhipster.json.2340439885' -> 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\insight-nodejs\Config\insight-generator-jhipster.json'
```

So, I right click on folder "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\insight-nodejs\Config" -> Uncheck "Read-only" attribute, then OK -> the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you need to remove the read-only flag of the file
(in my case file was located at C:\Users\Sanjay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\configstore)